# How to predict the location based on training data from CSV file in python and NLPK

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to predict the location-based one training data. I have data in below format.

Training Data:

```
Address Location_id Location_name
Flat No.201, MIDC, Andheri East, Mumbai, Maharashtra    121 Andheri East
Business Park, Goregaon, Mumbai, Maharashtra    122 Goregaon
Powai, Mumbai   123 Powai
Andheri East, Mumbai    121 Andheri East
Best Business Park, Goregaon, Mumbai    122 Goregaon
Hiranandani Park, Powai, Mumbai 123 Powai
```

Test Data:

```
plot no. 121, MIDC Area, Andheri East, Mumbai
```

Expected output:

```
To predict the location ID and Location Name.
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion NLPK is not appropriate here because you are not analyzing common words or sentences in a text with natural langage but just some proper nouns.

I don't know what is the purpose of your trial but you have to know that Machine Learning is not made for this type of problem with such a little amount of data.

If you are just trying to determine the city depending on the address I think you should better use Google Maps API or something similar.

Comment: Thank you, can you please suggest something? to do same task

Comment: I already suggested you to use [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/?hl=fr) which provides a platform with many different tools for this type of problems. But since i don't know the context and the purpose of your problem i can't help you more

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do requires simple logic.
You need to extract the Area name from the given address. If you just split the address by "," and return second last element, your task is done.

```
address.split(",")[-2]
```

Comment: What I have suggested seems very simple. but you can start from it and add more rules or RegEx

Comment: Can you please give some examples??

Comment: As I said first you try the simple thing which I suggested and see how many predictions you get right. Then analyse the addresses where you got wrong and identify some more patterns in them. In the examples shared by you the split logic would work 100% of the time

Comment: OK but In this case, all location is not the same position, some are with state name also. I have more than 2000 row to train data. Is it any way to train data using machine learning?

Comment: State names are very few and can be ignored with simple string matching with all possible state names. The whole point was to first see how many locations are wrongly identified and then as you said states can be there which can fail the logic so we try to overcome that. Machine Learning is not what you need here, area names, cities or state names are finite and can be memorized.  If you want to go for Machine Learning then try CRFs or LSTMs. Both these techniques are used to extract the desired sequence of text using labeled data.

Comment: I think if I can use NLP to train our model?

Comment: NLP libraries like Spacy are good when you have sentences and you need to extract some information from it. Here you have addresses which are in a specific format. Even you save all the location names and if you have enough labelled data than you can check test data for those saved names of location. So save Andheri, Goregaon,... and hope your labels would cover all the areas and check in new address for the presence of these areas.

Comment: Ok, how can get location I'd ?

Comment: Location Id has one to one mapping with Location name. Save this mapping from the labelled data